# What does this schematic symbol of two wires that are criss-crossed mean?

Tags: identification, symbol

I ran into this wiring symbol today and haven't been able to find out what it means. Somehow internet search of "criss-cross wire schematic symbol" wasn't especially fruitful.

Is this something I need to worry about or is this just a representation of a USB connection?

[image]

Comment: Well, I don't know but the symbol would suggest shielded twisted pair cable to me.

Comment: Twisted Shielded Pair with male pins on both ends of the cable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's showing the internal workings of a typical USB cable.  The shield (top line) is connected to the chassis of both devices.  USB Data- and USB Data+ are [twisted together](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_pair) for better noise rejection, at the cost of increased capacitance between the two.  Likewise, power (VBUS) and ground are twisted for the same reason.

Answer (score 15):

The crossed wires means that the cable must be a "Twisted pair".

Additionally, the dotted line indicates an RF shield (e.g. metal foil or braid).

Comment: I would prefer to say *dotted cylinder*